# log in to my website with assigned password from only one computer at a time

Tags: passwords

If I have a website mysite.com/camera and I have users subscribe by their email address and I assign a 8 digit (numbers/letters lower cse)password. What code do I need on what pages so the login checks if its valid, then checks if that combination is already in use

The username password list will be kept on another page that needs to be checked for validity when the user logs in.

I would like to set this up so that if a customer shares his username/password that at most only one friend can view at a time.

No login is being used at this time, right now it is a public page.

Comment: What's the address of the page where passwords are stored?

Answer (score 1):

You say the username password list is kept on another page.  You should use a database such as mysql to store the username/password list.  Create a table with fields userId, email, password, key - where userId is an identity field, and key is a guid.

When a user registers, create a new entry in the database with their email in the email field, password in the password field, and key guid defaulted to null or some initial guid value if you prefer not to allow nullable fields.

When a user logs in successfully (validates email/password against the database table), create a new guid, update the key field for the user with that guid, and drop a cookie for the user with the guid value. On every page on the site that requires being logged in, start by retrieving the user's guid from the cookie and querying the database to make sure an entry exists with that guid value.  If there is no entry, expire the cookie and log the user out.

What will happen is that a user's friend who tries to log in will generate a new guid and in effect "steal" the login.  The initial user will no longer have a valid guid cookie and will be logged out when they try to access a page.

Comment: Thanks Dan, How many hours does a project like this take to setup? I do HTML, a little PHP and javascript. Never did a database before. What is the code language that passes the username and password and sets the cookie?

Comment: If you've never setup a database driven site, it will likely take you a few days to get up to speed and learn basics. It's all done with a server side language like PHP or ASP.Net. If you already know some PHP, I'd recommend finding a tutorial on how to setup a mysql database, connect to and run simple sql queries.  PHP will also allow you to manage cookies.

Comment: One minor remark - please don't use GUID for your keys especially if your database will be SQL Server. It's a very inefficient choice in terms of storage, and it performs poorly as a clustering key. A integer identity field of appropriate size will suffice (int or bigint).